# Why is my AsyncStorage.getItem().then undefined in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using `AsyncStorage` to get information. I previously stored but for some strange reason it is saying `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` even though I use this exact same AsyncStorage function in the function below and it works just fine.  Does anyone know why this isn't working here?

```
AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_PRODUCT_SEARCH_CACHE).then((results) => {
    const searchCache = JSON.parse(results);
    let containedMatches = [];

    if (searchCache) {
        containedMatches = searchCache.filter((searchCacheItem, i) => {
            return searchCacheItem.includes(searchTerm);
        });    
    }

    dispatch({
            type: types.HANDLE_LOAD_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
            containedMatches
        }
    );
});
```

Here is a video I made of this. Sorry you can hear my co-workers in the background so you'll have to mute it.

https://youtu.be/qwhywbD74l8

Comment: Call Async Storage with await, this doc: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html. I think in this case AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_PRODUCT_SEARCH_CACHE) absolutely undefined, check your key, check your function save data, make sure you save data success in any context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `await` to wait the `async` operation to finish like this:

```
async setData() {
    var resultCache= await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_PRODUCT_SEARCH_CACHE);
}
```

you can do your further functional work using this code.

Comment: May I know why this solution is downvoted? Please check the code before doing any action.

Comment: I used this solution but I didn't assign the await AsyncStorage to a variable.  I wasn't the one to down vote it either.  Thx